# Spacing in Bar Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using the Highcharts (Bar), in which I need to add the spacing (padding ) between the lines (the number of records which is dynamically increased or decreased). I want to know using which of its property we can increase the spacing between the lines.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.groupPadding

Comment: Please provide a live demo of your chart (jsfiddle preferably).